# How to delete many-to-many relationship?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I have a many-to-many relationship (Car & driver) How, when deleting a Driver, delete a link in the driver_car table and delete cars that were bound to this driver, and vice versa, when deleting a car, simply delete a car and links in the driver_car table that are not associated with this by car?

My BaseEntity:

```
 @MappedSuperclass
    public abstract class BaseEntity {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
    
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Date created;
    
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Date updated;
    
    
        private Boolean visible;
    
        @Column(name = "image_url")
        private String imageUrl;
    
        public BaseEntity() {
            this.created = new Date();
            this.updated = new Date();
            this.visible = true;
        }
    
        @PreUpdate
        public void preUpdate() {
            this.updated = new Date();
        }
    
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public Date getCreated() {
            return created;
        }
    
        public void setCreated(Date created) {
            this.created = created;
        }
    
        public Date getUpdated() {
            return updated;
        }
    
        public void setUpdated(Date updated) {
            this.updated = updated;
        }
    
        public Boolean getVisible() {
            return visible;
        }
    
        public void setVisible(Boolean visible) {
            this.visible = visible;
        }
    
        public String getImageUrl() {
            return imageUrl;
        }
    
        public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
            this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        }
    }
```

My Driver:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "drivers")
public class Driver extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    private String notes;
    private double balance;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "driver_car",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "driver_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "car_id"))
    private Set<Car> cars;

    public Driver() {
        super();
        this.cars = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public Set<Car> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

    public void setCars(Set<Car> cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    public void setNotes(String notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
}
```

My Car:

```
@Entity
@Transactional
public class Car extends BaseEntity {

@Column(name = "cars_name")
private String carName;

private String color;

@Column(name = "engine_of_capacity")
private double engineCapacity;

@Column(name = "years_of_issue")
private Integer yearsOfIssue;

@Column(name = "car_number")
private String carNumber;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "cars", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Driver> drivers;

public Car() {
    super();
    drivers = new HashSet<>();
}

public Set<Driver> getDrivers() {
    return drivers;
}

public void setDrivers(Set<Driver> drivers) {
    this.drivers = drivers;
}

public String getCarNumber() {
    return carNumber;
}

public void setCarNumber(String carNumber) {
    this.carNumber = carNumber;
}

public String getCarName() {
    return carName;
}

public void setCarName(String carName) {
    this.carName = carName;
}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public double getEngineCapacity() {
    return engineCapacity;
}

public void setEngineCapacity(double engineCapacity) {
    this.engineCapacity = engineCapacity;
}

public Integer getYearsOfIssue() {
    return yearsOfIssue;
}

public void setYearsOfIssue(Integer yearsOfIssue) {
    this.yearsOfIssue = yearsOfIssue;
}
}
```

Delete Car:

```
@Override
public void delete(Long id) {
    entityManager.createQuery("delete from Car s where s.id = :id")
            .setParameter("id", id)
            .executeUpdate();
}
```

Delete Driver:

```
@Override
public void delete(Long id) {
    entityManager.createQuery("delete from Driver d where d.id = :id")
            .setParameter("id", id)
            .executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: At the moment, when deleting the driver, the driver and relation driver_car are deleted, but not deleting the car.

Comment: Why would you delete the car?  What if someone else is a driver of that car?

Comment: @Jim Garrison, I meant if there are no drivers with this car, only then delete it

Comment: @ArtemDubenko I think Jim Garrison is point out seems to be the result of an incorrectly design relationship. If that is the case, I agree with him. A car entity should not depend on the existence of a driver entity (or vice versa). In a perfectly design system, you should be able to have drivers without cars and cars without assigned drivers. You should, however, make sure than a driver doesn't have more than one car assigned to him or her, or that a car doesn't have more than one assigned driver UNLESS there is such thing as an alternate driver. And that should be another field in the table.

Comment: I also learned way back in the day, that a many-to-many relationship between entities is often a poor design decision. Many times, you can add a table in between( `Car` and `Driver` in this case) to create a 1-to-1 relationship between entities. Think about it. UPS has many vehicles and drivers. BUT when on-duty, a `Driver` is assigned to ONE `Car` and a `Car` has only ONE `Driver`. That means `Car` and `Driver` tables are not related to each other. However, when `OnDuty` a 1-to-1 relationship is created between them.

Comment: Later in the day, when the driver finishes his route and returns to this hub, only the `OnDuty` table is changed. The `Driver` still exist in the driver table and definitely the `Car` still exist in the car table. Creating and destroying these records is absurd in this scenario (since the driver wasn't fired and the vehicle is just parked). You will need these entities again the next day. So why destroy them?

Comment: @JimGarrison do you agree with everything I posted here? I definitely didn't want to "put words in your mouth". LOL

Comment: @hfontanez You are completely correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One should be very cautious about using `CascadeType.ALL` for `@ManyToMany` associations, since this might yield surprising results as described e.g. here:
https://thorben-janssen.com/best-practices-for-many-to-many-associations-with-hibernate-and-jpa/#The_CascadeType_you_should_avoid_at_all_costs

> In the best case, it only creates performance issues, but in the worst case, it might also remove more records than you intended.

So a better way would be e.g. to have a dedicated service logic which specifies exactly which entities are to be deleted and which of course also takes care of [synchronizing both sides of the association.](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/)
This way there can also be a simple check whether a previously associated `Car` has no more associated `Driver`s after one was deleted, so that the "orphan" `Car` can then be deleted as well.